# Using rvest to parse a dataframe column of class chr, containing html and non html input

Tags: html, r, dataframe, rvest

I'm new to rvest and playing with web scraping. Is there a way to use rvest that can parse a dataframe column of class chr containing html and non html input, specifically transforming the rows with html input into parsed text with no change otherwise?

```
# Assuming my dataframe is called 'df' and the chr column is named 'body'
# Create a new column called 'clean_body' to store the cleaned data

df$clean_body <- NA

# Iterate over each row and clean the 'body' column
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  # Check if the 'body' column value is not NA
  if (!is.na(df$body[i])) {
    # Check if the value contains HTML tags
    if (grepl("<.*?>", df$body[i])) {
      # If the value contains HTML tags, parse the HTML and store the cleaned text
      df$clean_body[i] <- html_text(read_html(df$body[i]))
    } else {
      # If the value doesn't contain HTML tags, keep the original value
      df$clean_body[i] <- df$body[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Using this logic, it returns an error - "Error in UseMethod("xml_text") :
no applicable method for 'xml_text' applied to an object of class "xml_document"

Comment: Can you share the URL? Difficult to help you based on your code alone

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example?  A small mocked-up data set should do the trick, or the first few rows of your real data if that's enough to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual data (content, amount, ratio of HTML vs text records), all you might need is to apply `rvest::minimal_html()` on the whole column first.

As `minimal_html()` does not work on a vector of strings, we need a way to apply it on each individual item, i.e. use something from apply or `purrr` map family, do a row-wise operation (`dplyr::rowwise()`) or for-loop though items. In example bellow it's handled through `sapply()`

```r
library(rvest)
df_ <- tibble::tibble(
  descr = c("text","body","html"),
  body = c(
    "test simple text",
    "<body>\n<p>test html body</p>\n<p></p>\n</body>",
    "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>title</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p>test html document</p>\n<p></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n")
  )
df_
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   descr body                                                                    
#>   <chr> <chr>                                                                   
#> 1 text  "test simple text"                                                      
#> 2 body  "<body>\n<p>test html body</p>\n<p></p>\n</body>"                       
#> 3 html  "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" con…
df_$clean_body <- sapply(df_$body, \(text) minimal_html(text) |> html_text() |> trimws(),
                        simplify = TRUE) 

df_[, c("descr", "clean_body", "body")]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   descr clean_body                  body                                        
#>   <chr> <chr>                       <chr>                                       
#> 1 text  "test simple text"          "test simple text"                          
#> 2 body  "test html body"            "<body>\n<p>test html body</p>\n<p></p>\n</…
#> 3 html  "title\ntest html document" "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta htt…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>